# I can't figure out how to click the mouse with the mouse button being pressed in Python

Tags: python, mouse

I'm trying to make a program that, when the left mouse button is pressed, the program automatically clicks the mouse repeatedly.

```
from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller, Listener
import time
import multiprocessing as mp
import keyboard

mouse = Controller()

sleepTime = 0.01

def on_click(*args):
    global clicker
    clicker = True

def Clicker():
    while clicker == True:
        mouse.click(Button.left)
        time.sleep(sleepTime)

with Listener(on_click=on_click) as listener:
    listener.join()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    p1 = mp.Process(target=Clicker)

    p1.start()

    while True:
        if keyboard.is_pressed("å"):
            p1.kill()
            quit()
```

This is what I have tried but can't seem to make it work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

##### There is a *little* problem in your logic.

When you left click, you trigger an on_click() that clicks the left mouse button, which triggers the on_click() function that clicks the left mouse button and so on...

You should try using a different mouse button or even keyboard keys.

##### How to do this?

Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73211169/22401692) for similar question.